# How to Clear the Header on the Extra Page Produced by \cleardoublepage

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, blank-page, book-class, cleardoublepage

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage % Force break to an odd-numbered page.

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1]
\addtocontents{toc}{TOC entry.}
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC output:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I remove the header on the extra page produced by `\cleardoublepage` so that an entirely blank page appears here at the end of the Contents page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the definition of `\cleardoublepage` (by adding `\ShowCommand\cleardoublepage` somewhere in your document and examining the `.log`):

```
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
```

It does the following, sequentially:

- Issues `\clearpage` to flush all pending floats, then
- Checks whether your document is set in `twoside` mode (`book` is set in `twoside` mode by default);

  - If you are in `twoside` mode, it checks if the current page - the new page - is odd or even (via `\ifodd\c@page`). If it is, it does nothing, because `\cleardoublepage` wants to end on an odd page. If, however, the page is even, it sets an empty box (via `\hbox{}` - this is literally just *something invisible*) and then issues a `\newpage` to get to an odd page.
  - Additional invisible content is set if you're also in `twocolumn` mode, since a `\newpage` could flush you to the top of the second column, not the next page.

So, you could perform this process manually knowing your circumstance:

```
% Mimic \cleardoublepage
\clearpage
\mbox{}% Set something invisible (\hbox{} would also work)
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
```

Or you could patch `\cleardoublepage` in the preamble using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\cleardoublepage}% <cmd>
  {\newpage}% <search>
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

Note that the patch will be global, unless you save the original definition and restore it as needed, or insert an adjustable command rather than `\thispagestyle{empty}` before the first `\newpage`.

Comment: Thank you kindly for these very helpful solutions.